# Express - how to block invalid http methods?

Tags: http, express, routes

I am getting invalid http methods (see below) which trigger timeout errors from my server as the route is valid. Is there any way to block all invalid requests in Express? I can't find anything on google. 
[image: Invalid http requests]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Take a whitelist approach

```
// before your other code check supported methods
// assuming these ones are, just add/remove ones to customize
if (!/^(GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)$/.test(req.method)) {
  res.status(400).end('bad request');
  return;
}

// your code goes here now
```

**or** use middleware if using express

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!/^(GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)$/.test(req.method)) {
    res.status(400).end('bad request');
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```

In the words of **Donald Rumsfeld**...

> Reports that say that something hasn't happened are always interesting to me, because as we know, there are known knowns; there are things we know we know. We also know there are known unknowns; that is to say we know there are some things we do not know. But there are also unknown unknowns – the ones we don't know we don't know. And if one looks throughout the history of our country and other free countries, it is the latter category that tend to be the difficult ones.

**tl;dr** Point being, you can only know what you know so use a whitelist.

Comment: as I was getting flooded with requests, I came up with a very similar solution

`app.use(function (req,res,next){
    var whiteList = ["GET","POST","HEAD"];
    if(whiteList.indexOf(req.method)!=-1) next();
    else  res.sendStatus(401);
  });`

Comment: middleware is also good if using express, can just not call next if methods don't match    http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html